# How to take exact id of a record and pass it to form action route using jQuery in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want to create and edit record in same page which they are shown. so, I have send the record data to modal, including record id.

**here is the code to send data to modal:**

```
<td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" onclick="edit_exchange_rate(this)"
    data-target="#edit_exchange_rate"
    data-id="{{$exchange_rate->id}}"
    data-from="{{$exchange_rate->from}}"
    data-to="{{$exchange_rate->to}}"
    data-rate="{{$exchange_rate->rate}}"
    data-reverse="{{$exchange_rate->reverse}}"
    class="dropdown-item"><i class="icon-pencil text-info"></i> Edit</a>
</td>
```

**here is my edit modal:**

```
{{--edit_exchange_rate modal_start--}}
<div id="edit_exchange_rate" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="p-2 modal-header bg-dark">
                <h6 class="modal-title">Edit exchange rate</h6>
            </div>

            <form  method="POST" id="edit_exchange_rate_form" action="{{ route('exchange_rate.update', $exchange_rate->id)}}" class="modal-body"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                @method('PATCH')
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="from_edit" class="text-right col-md-4 col-form-label">From</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select name="from" class="form-control select select2-hidden-accessible" id="from_edit" data-fouc>
                            @foreach($currencies as $currency)
                                <option value="{{$currency->name}}">{{$currency->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    @error('from')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="to_edit" class="text-right col-md-4 col-form-label">To</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <select name="to" class="form-control select select2-hidden-accessible" id="to_edit"  data-fouc>
                            @foreach($currencies as $currency)
                                <option value="{{$currency->name}}">{{$currency->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    @error('to')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
              
                <button type="submit" class="float-right btn btn-light">Save changes</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{--edit_exchange_rate modal_end--}}
```

**Here is my jQuery code which change the input values of modal for a specific record.**

```
function edit_exchange_rate(e) {
    var link = $(e);
    var modal = $('#edit_exchange_rate'),
        from = link.data('from'),
        to = link.data('to'),
        rate = link.data('rate'),
        reverse = link.data('reverse');

        modal.find('#from_edit').val(from).change();
        modal.find('#to_edit').val(to).change();
        modal.find('#rate_edit').val(rate).change();
        modal.find('#reverse_edit').val(reverse).change();
}
```

**The problem** is the form always takes the last record id.
I want that the form take the record id and submit it.
how to do this?

Comment: in my opinion, The most stable method of working is to use a hidden input element and write a value there and read it back.

Comment: Thanks @Enes KAYGUSUZ, I want to pass it in form action. is there any solution?

Comment: Hi , add `data-action="{{ route('exchange_rate.update', $exchange_rate->id)}}"` this as well as data-attr in your `a` tag . Then , inside your function use `$("#edit_exchange_rate_form").attr("action",link.data('action'))`

Comment: Thanks @Swati, It did worked. could you write it as answer that I check it as done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `data-attribute` to your `a` tag i.e :

```
<a data-action="{{ route('exchange_rate.update', $exchange_rate->id)}}" ..>Edit</a>
```

and then whenever your `a` tag is clicked use that attribute to assign `action` of form tag inside modal . i.e :

```
$("#edit_exchange_rate_form").attr("action",link.data('action'))
```